# Php array: How to use different values for a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$sql='SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE "'.$date.'"=Date';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $c=$row['id'];
}
```

This returns more than 1 value. How can i use the different values for another query?
Ex:

```
$sql2='SELECT name FROM TABLE2 WHERE name="'.$c.'" ';
```

PS: i know the code is not good

Comment: Hello! Could you elaborate more please? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Is this really what you meant "'.$date.'"=Date?

Comment: No @ingus, it's an example

Comment: its wrong example i m sure you wanted to do Date="'.$date.'"?

Comment: @Valentino è difficile da spiegare. Devo in pratica prendere N° risultati della prima query $sql e ognuno di questi risultati confrontarlo nella where di un'altra query .

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Not 100% sure but hope it helps ...

```
$sql='SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE Date = '.$date;
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $sql2='SELECT name FROM TABLE2 WHERE name="'.$row['id'].'" ';
    $sub_result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

Comment: i like this. let me try it

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if this s what you need but here we go:

```
$sql='SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE Date="'.$date.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $c=$row['id'];

    $sql2='SELECT name FROM TABLE2 WHERE name="'.$c.'" ';
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

Or with `LEFT JOIN`

```
$sql='SELECT table1.something, TABLE2.something2 
      FROM table1
      LEFT JOIN TABLE2  
      ON table1.id=TABLE2.name

      WHERE table1.Date="'.$date.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```